# how to write query to check whether given datetime comes between other two datetime spans?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working  MS-Access DB.

I am trying to write the query for the Datetime.

I am trying to check the availability of the new date between two dates.

Ex. I have already created record which have following data
in Batch Table.

There are Four fields...

BatchStartDate -  1-Sept-2015

BatchStartTime -  11 AM

BatchEndDate -   7-Sept-2015

BatchEndtime -   3 PM

Now , while adding another batch,  it should not be fall in to the above record's datetime span otherwise batches will clash.

There should be only one batch at a time.

Ex.

```
 The new batch should not be 1-Sept-2015 12 PM TO 7-Sept-2015  3 PM 

 The new batch should not be 1-Sept-2015 1 PM To 7-Sept-2015  4 PM 

 The new batch should not be 1-Sept-2015 2 PM To 7-Sept-2015  5 PM 

  The new batch should not be 3-Sept-2015 11 AM To 9-Sept-201 2 PM 

                       and So on...
```

means there will be n number of combinations that fall in two dates of First record.

**But I should add 1-Sept-2015 3.05 PM TO 7-Sept-2015  7 PM as it doesn't clash**

Now, I wan to write query to check newly adding record should fall in 1st record datetime span or not.

**Its not as simple, because on same day different batches can orgnize, so Between clause or range clause will not help...**

Answer (score 0):

I dont have sql server access now. So just check for syntax. Logically its correct as I have used like this.

```
SELCT * FROM **YOUR TABLE** 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(day,START-DATE,END-DATE) AS DiffDate)  
WHERE DiffDate<= **NUMBER OF DAYS YOU WANT**
```

Comment: I wan to check , whether date falls in above record or not...how date difference will help me ?

Comment: simply want to check whether date falls in given date range or not including , hours and minutes as well...

Comment: You know the date difference between those 2 dates.

Comment: Not getting, what is the use of date difference in this ?

Comment: So here, You can define the start date and end date will be the date of each tuple

Comment: Like I will say , start will be 1-sep and end date will be date of each tuple whcih should be less than 6 days ( to fall in between 7th sep)

Comment: If I try to add the same date but different time span. It should give zero records, If I try to add the BatchStartDate - 1-Sept-2015 BatchStartTime - 3 PM BatchEndDate - 7-Sept-2015 BatchEndtime - 6 PM ? Its a valid Batch time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a between clause:

```
SELECT * FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
WHERE <YOUR_DATE> BETWEEN <START_DATE> AND <END_DATE>;
```

Comment: this query works, If I try to add the same date but different time span.    It should give zero records, If I try to add  the                               BatchStartDate - 1-Sept-2015

BatchStartTime - 3 PM
                                                                                                                               
BatchEndDate - 7-Sept-2015

BatchEndtime - 6 PM ? Its a valid Batch time...

Comment: @user1650894, I'm not sure what your question is; can you try to re-phrase it?